# Characteristic function of the uniform random variable on $[0,1]^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution, characteristic-functions

> I need to calculate the characteristic function of the uniform variable on $[0,1]^2$.

My idea was the following:

Let $(X,Y)\sim \mathrm{Unif}\left([0,1]^2\right)$. First remark that $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=1_{[0,1]^2}(x,y)=1_{[0,1]}(x)1_{[0,1]}(y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ hence $X$ is independent from $Y$. Now $$\Phi_{(X,Y)}(u,v)=\Bbb{E}\left(e^{i\langle(u,v),(X,Y)\rangle}\right)=\Bbb{E}\left(e^{iuX}e^{ivY}\right)\stackrel{\text{independent}}{=}\Bbb{E}\left(e^{iuX}\right)\Bbb{E}\left(e^{ivY}\right)=\frac{e^{iu}-1}{iu}\cdot \frac{e^{iv}-1}{iv}. $$

Is this correct so or can't I do this like this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo is this your upvote and if yes how shold I interprete this does this mean that it's a nice question or that it's a correct way of solving it?

Comment: Yes, it was my upvote. The computation is correct but something has to be said when $uv=0$. It is both a nice question an a good way to solve it.

Comment: @Wave You should just add what happens when $u=0$ or $v=0$ or both. Just compute the limits and see that $\frac{e^{iu}-1}{iu}\to 1 $ as $u\to 0$. And use iterated limits. That is what Davide is trying to say.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed was I say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct. The key point was indeed to use independence between $X$ and $Y$.

Maybe you should precise what happens when $u$ or $v$ equals $0$ [there is no problem as you can take the limit as $u,v\to 0$].

Comment: Ah so I mean for a general characteristic function $\Phi_X$ we always have $\Phi_X(0)=\Bbb{E}(1)=1$ right? or is this not the argument we are looking for?